# I need to develop $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i}$ using the binomial coefficients formula and show a few properties

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In the previous questions I've proved that $(1+i)^{2n+1}=a_n+ib_n$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $\pm 2^n$ and that $(1-i)^{2n+1}=a_n - ib_n$ and that $|P_n(1)|=2^n$ using the previous statements. But now I need to show that the polynomial $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i}$ is of degree $2n$, even (the coefficient in front of $X^n$ is non-zero only when $n$ is even, with real coefficients, and with $2n+1$ as a dominant coefficient, using the binomial coefficient formula.

I also need to show that the coefficient $X^{2n-2}$ in $P_n$  is $\frac{n(1-2n)(1+2n)}{3}$.

I developed $(X+i)^{2n+1}$ and I get $X^{2n+1}+(2n+1)X^{2n}i-\frac{(2n+1)(2n)}{2}X^{2n-1}+...+(2n+1)X(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}$

When I develop $(X-i)^{2n+1}$ I get $X^{2n+1}+(2n+1)X^{2n}i-\frac{(2n+1)(2n)}{2}X^{2n-1}+...+(2n+1)X(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}$, so the same thing.

So obviously when I subtract the two parts I get $0$ which won't let me prove the properties. Where is my mistake ? Do I use the binomial coefficient the wrong way ?

EDIT: I think I have made a mistake in the second development, the second term should has a + sign when the subtraction is made so I get $\frac{2(2n+1)X^{2n}i}{2i} = (2n+1)X^{2n}$

How do I show it is even though ? Is the end result  enough to show this property?

Answer (score 1):

From the binomial theorem,
$$(x+a)^{2n+1}=\sum_{m=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose m}x^ma^{2n+1-m}$$
so
$$\begin{align}
(x+a)^{2n+1}-(x-a)^{2n+1}&=\sum_{m=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose m}x^m(a^{2n+1-m}-(-a)^{2n+1-m})\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose m}x^ma^{2n+1-m}(1-(-1)^{2n+1-m})\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose m}x^ma^{2n+1-m}(1+(-1)^{m}).
\end{align}$$
Then, when $m$ is even, $(-1)^m=1$, and $1+(-1)^m=1+1=2$. Thus all the terms where $m=2k$ is even are non-zero, and we have
$$\sum_{0\le m\le2n+1\\ m \text{ is even}}{2n+1\choose m}x^{m}a^{2n+1-m}(1+(-1)^{m})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k}a^{2n+1-2k}(1+(-1)^{2k})\\
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k}a^{2n-2k+1}.$$
Then, when $m$ is odd, $(-1)^m=-1$, and $1+(-1)^m=1-1=0$. Thus all the terms where $m=2k+1$ is odd are $0$, and we have
$$\sum_{0\le m\le2n+1\\ m \text{ is odd}}{2n+1\choose m}x^{m}a^{2n+1-m}(1+(-1)^{m})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2k+1}x^{2k+1}a^{2n+1-2k-1}(1+(-1)^{2k+1})\\
=0.$$
Then,
$$\begin{align}
(x+a)^{2n+1}-(x-a)^{2n-1}&=\sum_{0\le m\le2n+1\\ m \text{ is even}}{2n+1\choose m}x^{m}a^{2n+1-m}(1+(-1)^{m})\\
&+\sum_{0\le m\le2n+1\\ m \text{ is odd}}{2n+1\choose m}x^{m}a^{2n+1-m}(1+(-1)^{m})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k}a^{2n+1-2k}(1+(-1)^{2k})\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k}a^{2n-2k+1}.
\end{align}$$
If you set $a=i$ you see that $a^{2n-2k+1}=(i^2)^{n-k}\cdot i=(-1)^{n-k}\cdot i$. Thus
$$(x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}=2i\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k},$$
and, finally,
$$p_n(x)=\frac1{2i}((x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}{2n+1\choose 2k}x^{2k}.$$
You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: When i try to compute the $X^{2n-2}$ term, so when $k=n-2$ I get $\frac{n\left(2n+1\right)\left(2n-1\right)\left(n-1\right)\left(2n-3\right)}{30}$ but I need to find $\frac{n(1−2n)(1+2n)}{3}$

Comment: @RoyalValue We have that the coefficient of $x^{2n-2}$ is given by $$-{2n+1\choose 2n-2}=-\frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n-2)!(2n+1-2n+2)!}=-\frac{(2n+1)(2n)!}{3!(2n-2)!}=-\frac{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)!}{6(2n-2)!}=-\frac{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)!}{6(2n-2)!}=\frac{1}{3}n(1-2n)(1+2n)$$

Comment: your error is that you are setting $k=n-2$, while you should be setting $k=n-1$, because $2k=2n-2$.

Comment: Oh my bad! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RoyalValue I'm very glad I could help :)

Comment: In the third step of $(x+a)^{2n+1}−(x−a)^{2n+1}$, shouldn't the k be an m instead in the binomial coefficient ? Also $(−1)^{2n+1−m}$ become $(-1)^{m}$ because odd power of $-1$ are $-1$ ?

Comment: @RoyalValue Ah yes thanks for catching that, I fixed it. We have $(-1)^{2n+1-m}=(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot(-1)^{-m}=-1\cdot (-1)^{m}$

Answer (score 0):

In the expansion
$$(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}X^ki^{2n+1-k}- \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}X^k(-i)^{2n+1-k}$$
the terms  such that $2n+1-k$ is even, i.e. k is odd, cancel pairwise, so there remains the terms with $k=2\ell+1\enspace (0\le \ell\le n)$, and the final expansion is
\begin{align}(X+i)^{2n+1} &- (X - i)^{2n+1}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2\ell} X^{2\ell}2\,i^{2(n-\ell)}\\
&=2\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2\ell} X^{2\ell}(-1)^{n-\ell}.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand why it cancels pairwise, for me $i^{2n+1} = (-i)^{2n+1}$ because $(-i)^2 = i^2 = -1$ so $(-i)^{2n+1} = (-1)^{n+1}$. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No, it is $(-1)^{2n+1} i^{2n+1}=-\bigl(i^{2n+1}\bigr)$, and you subtract $(X-i)^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$\begin{array}\\
(a+b)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}\\
(x+i)^{2n+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k}x^ki^{2n+1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}i^{2n+1-2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}i^{2n+1-(2k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}i^{2(n-k)+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}i^{2(n-k)}\\
&=i\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k}\\
(x-i)^{2n+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k}x^k(-1)^{2n+1-k}i^{2n+1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{2n+1-2k}i^{2n+1-2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(-1)^{2n+1-(2k+1)}i^{2n+1-(2k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{2(n-k)+1}i^{2(n-k)+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(-1)^{2(n-k)}i^{2(n-k)}\\
&=-i\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k}\\
\end{array}
$

If we subtract the terms
the second term cancels out and we are left with

$\begin{array}\\
(x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}
&=i\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}-(-i\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k})\\
&=2i\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{(x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}}{2i}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}\\
\end{array}
$

The highest order term has
$k = n$
so it is
$(2n+1)x^{2n}
$.

If we add the terms
instead of subtracting,
the first term cancels out and we are left with

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(x+i)^{2n+1}+(x-i)^{2n+1}}{2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k}\
\end{array}
$

The highest order term has
$k = n$
so it is
$x^{2n+1}
$.